Minimum bound on grid element for game of row doubles and column decrements
The rules of a game are described below:

A rectangular grid is composed of n columns and w rows; n and w are finite.
At the start of the game, each grid element is occupied by a natural number ≤ m.
The player may choose to double each element of a row or decrement every number in a column by 1.
The aim of the game is to reduce every number in the grid to zero through a series of row doublings and column decrements.

Prove that any w by n grid with finite m can be reduced to a grid of zeroes through the allowed operations without any grid element ever exceeding a bound B.
Find B as a function of w, n, and m, as necessary.
If you're having trouble interpreting these rules, you can play this game here. You will be asked to enter w, n, and m. This game has bound B = 100,000.
I will add this:
I have noted, or at least hypothesized, the following:

Any individual column, or grid of n = 1, can be completed without any column element exceeding m.

I have hypothesized that the number of rows, w, does not affect B.

I think that if the largest number in a column, a, differs from the smallest number in a column, b, in a manner such that b > a - b,
then that column can be reduced to zero without the number of
doublings exceeding the number of odd prime factors of numbers in
that column plus one.



Welcome to math SE. What to you think? Have you tried anything?

Math.SE is not a homework machine. Attach your attempts and some context to get helped.

This is not homework. It's just a problem I am putting forth.
